# Symfony2 - Showing a page for a user to confirm input form values

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a long form that an user has to fill. After the user has clicked submit, I have to show a page with the information the user has filled in the form so that he can check that everything is correct before doing any further processing (i.e., he has to press another submit button or a back button if he detects an error).

Is there an easy way to do this? Is there a better way than creating a new form with hidden values equal to the values submitted in the previous form?

Would it be okay if I just store the information in a session variable and then process it if the user confirms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could skin that cat many ways, here's a couple of ideas:

1. Add a non-mapped confirm input (like a checkbox) to your form. On initial form render with no POST, hide the input. When you get a POST, show the checkbox input & some additional information (please review your data & check to confirm all is OK etc). Don't validate the form or save your data until the confirm input has been checked. You don't need to mess about with hidden fields, the one form will do the job for you.
2. Save the entity and give it a property e.g. isApproved, that way you can show the data easily & if the user needs to edit, re-use your form. When the user approves the information set isApproved to true. Don't perform any actions on any entities that have isApproved == false. Cons are you then have to manage an isApproved state for an entity.